# How to select two different datasets with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select two data sets from the same table, instead of doing two queries I am trying to select them both in one call.

First of all I want to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM `Messages` WHERE `id` = '1';
```

and the second is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total_read` FROM `Messages` WHERE `id` = '1' AND `read` = '1';
```

Is there anyway to do this in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) total,
    SUM(IF(read='1',1,0)) total_read
FROM Messages
WHERE id='1';
```

Comment: It works just fine: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78c30/2.  However, you do need to put tick-marks around `read` since it is a mysql keyword.

Comment: I always use tick marks, since it makes it easier to read the SQL.